# How to include SCSS files for Angular 5 in Rails 5 with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, sass, webpacker

I'm trying to setup a new Rails project with webpacker and Angular. The basic setup is working, but I'm not able to include custom SCSS files. I followed the steps in the blog post [Angular with Rails and Webpacker](https://www.spectory.com/blog/Angular%202%20with%20Rails%20and%20Webpacker), but I wasn't able to get it up and running. I end up with the error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--2-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--2-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-4!./node_modules/to-string-loader/src/to-string.js!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./app/javascript/hello_angular/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed: 
h1 {
^
      Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var result = requir"
      in /Users/florianfeldhaus/IdeaProjects/rails-test/app/javascript/hello_angular/app/app.component.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

[I documented all steps I carried out](https://github.com/ffeldhaus/rails-test/blob/master/Setup.md) (I tried first without and then with the hack described in the blog post), but couldn't get it to work. [I shared a minimal project (e.g. without the HTML template) on GitHub](https://github.com/ffeldhaus/rails-test).

- What do I need to do to include SCSS files for an Angular 5 App served with Rails 5 with Webpacker?
- Is there any full, up to date tutorial or documentation available for this setup?

Comment: I think you only need to `import` them on your JS entry file. I have a `packs` dir and a `styles` dir, etc, from a pack file I call `import '../styles/main.scss';`. I'm not sure relatively to Angular (since I use vue and it splits the CSS from the single component if I use) but I imagine you would load the component SCSS file in the component itself, and then webpack will be able to create the dependency graph based on the `import`/`require` statement. I think I didn't need to install any extra loader with Webpacker

Comment: maybe you're missing your `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'hello_angular' %>`? Had the same issue but with react

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue right now and can't find any kind of updated documentation for running Rails 5 / Angular 5 / Webpacker

Comment: Unfortunately I didn’t find a solution. I had to fall back to pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to this myself. I believe the problem is that the sass-loader is already being included somewhere by default. When you go to add it to your loaders in environment.js, it's actually trying load sass-loader twice and causing a cryptic error. So the solution is to use the following code to overwrite the existing entry and then also include css-loader and to-string-loader in order to include it in your Angular component.

```
environment.loaders.insert('sass', {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        "to-string-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
        "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
        "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
    ]
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you HAVE TO name the loader 'sass' to overwrite the default sass loader that ships with webpacker.